# add onclick listener to a button in a fragment's xml

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm writing and android 4.4 project using android studio.

I'm new to the fragments idea and trying to create a simple application with a button that the click handler sends a message to the log.

this is the fragment class

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void addStringClickHandler(View v) {
        Log.d("tag","hello");
    }
}
```

this is the fragment layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.tuxin.myalcoholist.myalcoholist.myalcoholist.MainMenuActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_drink"
    android:id="@+id/add_drink"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:onClick="addStringClickHandler" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see i set in the XML android:onclick to addStringClickHandler
and in the fragment class i created that function, but when I execute the application
I get an error that the runtime could not find a method addStringClickHandler(view)

what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `android:onClick` handler method has to belong to the Activity hosting your fragment. Just move `addStringClickHandler()` method to the activity.

If you want to have a listener method in the fragment you have to set listener in the code like this.

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
     rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_drink).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("tag","hello");
         }
     });
     return rootView;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the `onClick` method when inflating the view.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_drink).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do what you need               
    }
});
return rootView;
```

Or you can set the fragment to be the on click listener

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_drink).setOnClickListener(this);
return rootView;
```

and then make the fragment implement `OnClickListener`.